# How to create a modular system of multiple .NET Core applications extending a single application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

**So first of all let me explain what I want to achieve:**

I want to create a basic .NET Core console application which is responsible for loading external extensions (more on this later on), listening for events, connection handling etc.

Let's assume this application is a Discord bot or Amazon's Alexa. It is responsible for starting, shutting down, connecting and so on. This core application relies on a external Nuget package.

But you want to provide a system to extend this basic application with a plug n play system. So instead of extending the core Git repository (e.g. on Github) you would create another repository with a .NET Core library which provides a new feature/command/skill. This extending project also adds a dependency to the external Nuget package.

At the end you would have a core application in one repository and multiple repositories extending the core application.

**How to develop this?**

Let's assume

- Developer A creates the core application in a repository *myApp.core*
- Developer B wants to create a "Hello World" command in a separate repository *myApp.extensions.hello-world*
- Developer C wants to create a "Ping" command in a separate repository *myApp.extensions.ping*

Developer A could work on the application it's easy to test locally.

Developers B and C create libraries for their features. To get their libraries loaded into the application Developer A loads all DLL files from a specific directory *"Extensions"* during startup.

The external Nuget package searches for every implementation of commands. So those extending projects only provide implementations of new commands. The core application only provides connection handling etc.

But how could Developers B and C test their new features if they want to debug the libraries in their IDEs? They can't run that library so they have to test that library by running the core application.

Things might get tricky if developer A is an employee and developer B and C are just customers creating their own commands but don't have access to the core application.

So how would developers B and C debug their libraries locally then? Are there any better approaches for this? Maybe Docker helps out?

**Let me give a real world scenario**

Developers A, B and C want to create a Discord bot.

- Developer A creates a repository for the bot core functionality e.g. connecting against the Discord chat
- Developer B creates another repository for a simple bot command
- Developer C creates another repository to listen for new users in a specific guild

All three developers import the Nuget package for the Discord C# library. Developers B and C only create libraries with command/event implementations of interfaces provided by that Nuget library.

B wants to test the command, C wants to test the event listener. Both have to run the bot from the repository of A. Or not?

Comment: Developers B and C would create Unit Test Projects and use them to test their libraries. There is no need for them to use the Core Console application. In addition, instead of using Extensions (I'm assuming you mean SVN extensions), developers B and C could 'release' or 'tag' their assemblies and developer A could update his project with the latest B/C assembles at his convenience.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Have no access to the core application". Does this mean that the customers will create the extensions and then give them to you to run them with the core application, while they never see the core application? Why can't they use the core application? Isn't it possible to create 'boostrapping' core application they can use for debugging?

Comment: @quaabaam yes, they might just unit test it. But they rely on a valid connection etc. so it would be nice to make use of the core application

Comment: @Euphoric well for my case they have access to the core repository. But how would you debug the library in your IDE? You have to point to the .exe of the core application right?

Comment: When does the extension get added to the "main" console? Is it a (pre-compilation) project/nuget reference, or are you expecting your post-compilation console application to dynamically load any extensions you put next to it?

Comment: Since I thought the core application shouldn't know about the extension libraries I thought it would be the best to search for all DLLs during startup and load them dinamically

Answer (score 1):

The extension developers can create a "bootstrap" console application next to their library. This bootstrap application could start the core application with the plugin (or plugins).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var coreApp = new CoreApp();
        coreApp.AddExtension(new MyExtension());
        coreApp.Run();
    }
}
```

This should be possible if you want to invest time and effort into improving extension developer's experience of creating the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcomplicate things. Developers B and C can just build themselves a simple CLI/Test Harness who's only purpose is to new up the commands in their libraries and exercise the commands they are responsible for.

Comment: the problem is that those features rely on a connection. So they have to make use of the core application

Comment: of course you could code it twice, for a test scenario, but this would be redundant code

Comment: @OlafSvenson, they don't need the core application, they need a connection to send data over.  They won't (shouldn't) care what's on the other side.  

They can mock out whatever connections they need that provide fake responses. A bit of repetition isn't necessarily a bad thing if it lets them confidently test their pieces in isolation

Answer (score 0):

I would argue developers B and C must have some kind of access to the application.

Without the application it will be impossible to do comprehensive testing. Unit tests and/or custom test harnesses are good, but since they are written by the plugin developers they can only test how they think the application works, not how it actually works. Developer A could build and publish a separate test harness that simulates the real application, but there is always the risk that there are differences between the test harness and the real application.

Good API design and documentation can reduce the need for testing with the real application, and may be sufficient for a fairly simple API. But I would not like to release a plugin without at least some testing with the real application.

Exactly how you distribute the application to the plugin developers depends on your needs. Simplest would be to just send the application upon request, or publish the source and let them compile it themselves. More elaborate designs might involve a special license or version that reduces functionality in a way to still allow testing, but make it infeasible to use for production. More details are needed for more concrete suggestions.

An example could be AWS lambda. You download a test harness so you can run your project locally and debug it. Once you are satisfied you can upload it and test it on the real servers, but with much more limited debugging support.

Comment: I updated my question with a real world example :)

Comment: @Olfa Svenson All three need to run the bot, but B and C do not necessarily need to run it from the repository. A could create a build and give it to B and C. I was asking more about the code sharing policy A have. Can the source for the bot be freely shared? Is the code super-secret and is not permitted to leave a restricted network? perhaps not even in binary form? Somewhere in between?

Comment: B and C have access to the repository of A :)

Comment: but what if not? E.g. developing skills for Amazon's Alexa?

Comment: _"but since they are written by the plugin developers they can only test how they think the application works, not how it actually works"_ The core app developers can logically only test for adherence to the contracts (e.g. interfaces) that the core app exports to its extensions. That's logically inevitable, but more importantly the core app developers never need to care about anything more. The extension developers can still test specific additional behaviors related to their specific implementation. Each developer should only write code for the part that they control/care about.

Comment: To put it a different way, if we both write an `ICar` implementation, we can both use the core app's `CarMovesForward` test, since this is basic `ICar` contract adherence - cars have to be able to move forward. However, your fuel combustion car will need its own specific `TankHasFuel` test, and my hamster-wheel-engined care will needs its own specific `HamsterIsNotDead` test. The `ICar` developers never cared about fuel or hamsters, and never should care about it. But we do care about our specific implementation (respectively), so _**we**_ test for it (respectively).

Comment: Note that I'm not arguing against integration tests with the real app (or some core-developer-approved mock thereof), but both sides should have their own testing because they have their own reasons for doing so. Core app developers test (and provide reusable tests) for core contract adherence, and extension developers can further supplement those tests with their own implementation-specific tests, where they feel it is warranted.

Comment: @Flater Yes, but quite often APIs are ambiguous. Is the method threadsafe? Does it accept null arguments? If the documentation does not specify this you have to guess. And even if you have excellent documentation there might still be bugs that you either need to workaround or contact the developers to have fixed. Tests and local mocks etc are good, but I argue that releasing without **any** representative integration tests are a bad idea for non trivial applications.

Comment: @JonasH: Hence the ability for the library (i.e. core app) developers to include specific tests that the extension developers can execute to confirm the correct implementation. Need null handling? Write a test for null input. Obviously documentation would go great with it, but the tests themselves act as a line of defense for things you forgot to read from the documentation. Integration tests are fine and dandy but they do not replace unit tests. They add value, but it's _different_ value than you get from unit tests. The issues you pointed out as examples are unit testable.

Comment: @flater sure But can you guarantee that the test cover 100% of all possible use cases?  And Match the real application 100%? And is continually updated for each version? Again, I'm not arguing that unit tests are not useful, just that they are not sufficient.

Comment: @JonasH: No one can ever 100% guarantee that a developer writes the correct unit tests, or that in the future a developer will keep their tests updated (or anything else, for that matter). That just doesn't make sense as a standard. _Nothing_ can be guaranteed about what another person may or may not do and whether they do it well or not.

Answer (score -1):

Your core application must expose a public API which can be used by other libraries. Preferably, this API would be a simple or a set of simple interfaces. Library projects can then install your core application as a NuGet package and implement its interface(s).

When you implement the interface(s), you have a dependency from the external libraries to your core application. This way developers B and C can easily develop and debug their libraries.

Developer A, on the other hand, doesn't need to reference the libraries of developers B and C. Developer A can use `System.Reflection` to find all implementations of the core app's interfaces during runtime.

For example, let's say that your core app has an interface called `IInitializer`. And let's say that every library needs to implement this interface because that's how your core app will initialize the library before using it.

Developer A now wants to fetch all of the implementations of the `IInitializer` interface from the core app without having a dependency from the core app to the custom library like so:

```
private IEnumerable<IInitializer> GetInitializerImplementations(Assembly assembly)
{
    var initializerImplementations = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                        where type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IInitializer)) &&
                            type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                        select Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IInitializer;
    return initializerImplementations;
}
```

Developer A has now just loaded all the implementations of the `IInitializer` interface during runtime. You can iterate through them and use them as you want.

All that's left is to find the assemblies of the libraries and pass them to the method which I wrote, but you said you already know where to find these assemblies.

Also, have a look at this blog post:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/744862/Dependency-injection-in-class-libraries.

It's a great post which shows exactly what you need.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but how would you debug the library? I have to point to the .exe of the core application, no?

Comment: Library devs can create a console app for testing purposes and you can expose a method in your core app which they could call from their console app. This exposed method would act as an entry point.